# VS2015 cannot start local debugging on VPN error about remote debugger

Tags: winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2015, local, remote-debugging

Recently I started having issues starting a LOCAL EXE (winforms or console applications, VB.NET 4.0 framework target).
To be clear I'm NOT doing remote debugging!

I am using AVAYA VPN client to connect to work but no networking should be needed to do local debugging.

If I disconnect the VPN it works normally again, so it is clearly related. But I have been using this VPN for years and until the last few weeks had not had this issue.

These are the 2 windows that popup when starting the program, the first one only pops up once after visual studio starts fresh, the second one occurs every time I try to run any project.

[image]
[image]

It appears VS2015 is confused and is trying to do remote debugging for no reason.

These are the things I tried so far

- Run the project without debugging (compiles and works fine)
- Restart VS (2015).
- Restart computer.
- Create fresh new project with minimal code (problem still exists).
- Enable remote debugging, run, then disable remote debugging.
- Clean Solution, Rebuild Solution.

If anyone has any suggestions or had similar issue and a way to correct it, please assist, this is killing me. :)

**NEW INFO**

I changed the project to x86 and it now runs. So this seems to be related to 64bit debugging. Possibly the remote debugger is used to connect to the 64bit process from the 32bit visual studio. This at least gives me a work around but would still like 64bit debug to work while on VPN.

If Visual Studio is already been debugging before the VPN connects, after you connect msvsmon.exe crashes immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run Visual studio remote debugger on your local machine as Administrator (it's important to run as administrator) after that Visual studio will be able to attach to process over VPN.

UPDATE: there is a Qualifier, you have to choose your remote debugger session instead of local machine, press find button and you will see it, it may have name MachineName:RemoteDebuggerPort, or IP address like in my case on screenshot

[image]

[image]

Remote debugger location for VS2017: 
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe**

Comment: Reasonable idea, but no dice.
I already have UAC turned off completely and VS already runs as administrator regardless. I did also try manually starting the process before beginning a debug session, with "Run as Administrator" but VS still starts it's own copy of the remote debugger, and fails with the same message. 
Also tried manually "Run As Admin" for VS as well, but same thing.

Comment: check update which I provided, if it helps to you. not only VS should be run as admin, but remote debugger as well.

Comment: Ok, now this is interesting. It is working if I do this very specific way to attach using what you suggest by starting without debug and attach it still doesn't work by computer name (default). but as you put in the image "127.0.0.1:4020" the FIND still causes me issues. BUT if I simply click refresh on the list of processes it Does allow me attach to the process and do debug with breakpoints. A little cumbersome but it works. :)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue and can't even attach the process. If I try to attach the process I get the error as below : Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named '127.0.0.1:4020'.  The Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging

Comment: Run a remote debugger from this location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2017 and Cisco AnyConnect VPN. I had to jump through a few more hoops to get this working.

1. Start the 64-bit MSVSMON as described in the other answer.
2. In the project settings, select "Remote Windows Debugger".
3. Set "Remote Command" to $(TargetPath).
4. Set "Remote Server Name" to 127.0.0.1:port where 'port' is taken from the output of MSVSMON (in my case, 4022).

Comment: "In the project settings" where in the project settings? I'm assuming you're referring to the Visual Studio project? There a project *properties* but no project *settings*.

Comment: Also, the port is incremented by 2 for every version of Visual Studio (2019 is port 4024): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2019