# Visual Studio 2019 Debugging does not work when VPN is connected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, vpn

- OS: Windows 10 (with current latest updates)
- IDE: Visual Studio 2019 v.16.4.4

Visual Studio cannot debug an ASP.NET Core 3 web application when the computer is connect to VPN (via Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client). The web application is dockerized and is started via docker-compose.

As mentioned [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/209932/debugging-not-work-if-we-use-vpn.html) the issue must have been resolved by now; however, at least on my end, it is not resolved yet.

I have tried setting up *remote debugging* following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Attach_to_a_process_on_a_remote_computer), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34915343/947889), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50400637/947889) documentation/suggestions. However, neither help debugging my web application when the computer is connected to VPN.

*I need to keep the computer connected to VPN because the application requires data that are available via my institute's VPN.*

Comment: The VPN client likely changes the default route which may make some addresses, especially the ones you want to use for remote debugging, unreachable. Check which route is used to the needed addresses and insert static routes to them in the routing table manually. Or try to restrict the routes the VPN client add to only the remote networks reached via VPN. If this is possible in the VPN client.

Comment: Is the VPN using the same subnets as Docker?

Comment: @stickybit not sure if any of those are configurable in the VPN client; do you have any specific steps I should take?

Comment: The steps i already wrote.

Comment: if you mean inserting the routes in "Remote debugger", I don't see an option inserting routs. If you mean in the "Attach Process" window, neither I see an option to modify the processes it can attach to.

Comment: If the VPN commandeers the default route, and there are no exceptions, there's a good chance there is no workaround for this.  It's entirely on the VPN monopolizing the network routing.

Comment: Nah, none of that. I mean the routes to the target addresses especially the next hop (router). You can use `tracert` (in a shell) to get that. And I mean the routing table of the OS. You can show or manipulate that with `route` (also in a shell). But none of these are a programming topic. So questions regarding that better fit [Super User](https://superuser.com) or maybe [Network Eningeering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Then can this question be transferred to "Super User"?

Comment: @Hamed I would disagree this belongs on Super User or Network Engineering (I think sticky meant the topics of using `tracrt`, anyway); *this* question is a specific configuration issue with using IIS Express (or other debugger) and Visual Studio in concert with a VPN -- tools used primarily by programmers for programming. That makes this question explicitly on-topic here. Out of curiosity (it's been 2 months), are you still having this issue? Also, do you encounter the issue for web projects that don't rely on Docker? I'm having the same issue but sans Docker.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks for the comment. Yes, unfortunately I have not resolved the issue yet. And, I just tested a webapp sans Docker, and it seems VS can connect to the debugger.

Comment: @Hamed Interesting, so that definitely makes it something related to Docker.

Comment: I guess so. I guess visual studio needs to be able to communicate with a docker container for debugging, and it cannot while connected to VPN. Disconnect the VPN, and all goes back to functional.

Comment: Possibly related https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/17